# Is there a built-in function for Multiple Zeta Values?

Tags: special-functions

For a sequence of positive integers $s_{1},\ldots ,s_{k}$, all greater than or equal to $2$, let

$$
\displaystyle \zeta (s_{1},\ldots ,s_{k})=\sum _{{n_{1}>n_{2}>\cdots >n_{k}>0}}\ {\frac  {1}{n_{1}^{{s_{1}}}\cdots n_{k}^{{s_{k}}}}}
$$

denote the corresponding Multiple Zeta Value (MZV).

Mathematica has many built-in functions for variants of the Riemann $\zeta$-function and Dirichlet $L$-functions, but I have not seen one that corresponds to MZVs (and it is not mentioned in the online documentation for [special functions](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/tutorial/SpecialFunctions.html)).

> Is there a built-in Mathematica function for MZVs?

Comment: There is a (not built-in ) package called PolyLogTools (see here https://inspirehep.net/record/1730046 ) or HPL which can be downloaded from the same source. It works up to weight 6.

If you have access to maple you could use "HyperInt" by Erik Panzer which has lookup tables up to weight 12  (see here: https://inspirehep.net/record/1285754 ) .

If you want to do numerical evaluations however, only PolyLogTools but not HyperInt allow (indirectly) for it.

Comment: @Armin Very interesting indeed. I will look that up.